# Pasting text including delimiters into Vuetify combobox does not separate the chips accordingly the delimiters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a Vuetify combobox with chips splitting what I'm pasting into it according to the delimiters that are defined for that component, for instance `,`. Meaning that if I'm pasting the text `a,b,c`, the component should turn them into 3 different chips: `a`, `b` and `c` but it does not work as such.

- Full Vue Source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/chips-so-0gp7g?file=/src/domains/experimental/Experimental.vue
- Preview: https://0gp7g.csb.app/experimental
- Relevant piece of Vue Source Code:

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-combobox
          v-model="chips"
          chips
          :delimiters="[',']"
          append-icon=""
          clearable
          hint="Hey I'm a  hint!"
          persistent-hint
          label="Type your favorite s"
          multiple
          solo
          @update:search-input="meowInput"
        >
          <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item }">
            <v-chip
              v-bind="attrs"
              close
              :color="getColor(item)"
              @click:close="remove(item)"
            >
              <strong>{{ item }}</strong
              >&nbsp;
            </v-chip>
          </template>
        </v-combobox>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import ColorHash from "color-hash";

export default {
  name: "Experimental",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      select: [],
      chips: [],
      search: "", //sync search
    };
  },
  methods: {
    meowInput(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
    getColor(item) {
      const colorHash = new ColorHash({ lightness: 0.9 });
      return colorHash.hex(item);
    },
    remove(item) {
      this.chips.splice(this.chips.indexOf(item), 1);
      this.chips = [...this.chips];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Any idea about how can I achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bind and sync with the change of `search-input`, the rest is to split the search value and concat to the chips

> `search-input`: Search value. Can be used with `.sync` modifier.

```
<v-combobox
  // ...
  :search-input.sync="search"
  // ...
>

// ... 

meowInput(e1) {
  if (this.search && this.search.split(",").length > 1) {
    this.chips = this.chips.concat(
      this.search.split(",").filter((term) => !this.chips.includes(term))
    );
    this.search = "";
  }
}
```

**Forked demo**

[image: Edit Chips SO (forked)]

Comment: @KerryPerret no prob, glad that it could help